# how to insert into mysql from an html select multiple

Tags: php, mysql

How to insert into MySQL from an HTML select multiple

This is my code HTML:

```
<select name="domaine[]" id="domaine" class="validate[required]" multiple>
            <option></option>
            <option value="WEB">WEB</option>
            <option value="Java2EE">Java2EE</option>
            <option value="android">android</option>
            <option value="VB.Net">VB.Net</option>
            <option value="iOS">iOS</option>
            <option value="C++">C++</option>
</select>
```

This is my php code:

```
try{
        $cdb=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=source', 'root','');

}  catch (Exception $e){
    die("erreur".$e->getMessage());

}  
$cin=$_SESSION['cin'];

$rep=$cdb->prepare("insert into dev (cin,comp)values('$cin','".$_POST["domaine"]."')");
$rep->execute();
```

Comment: Aaaaaaaah that prepare is making my eyes bleed. Please, [use prepares correctly and without string interpolation or not at all](http://php.net/pdo)

Answer (score 2):

It's very nice that you're using PDO, but your code is still vulnerable.  `VALUES` takes multiple arguments.

```
if (isset($_POST['domaine']) && is_array($_POST['domaine'])) {
    //(?,?),(?,?),(?,?) for 3 domaine
    $values = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($_POST['domaine']), '(?,?)'));
    $query = "INSERT INTO dev (cin, comp) VALUES $values";
    $params = array();
    foreach ($_POST['domaine'] as $d) {
        array_push($params, $cin, $d);
    }
    $rep = $cdb->prepare($query);
    $rep->execute($params);
}
```

You could also `prepare` a single `INSERT` statement and loop over `execute`, but I believe this is more efficient.

Comment: Saves me the trouble of throwing the prepared statements page at the OP in an answer. ++.

Comment: it's work thanks.....when I want to make update for each CIN and I want to save it in one case like this : web,java2EE,android... how?? and thanks

Comment: @mamoud oh, I wish you would have told me that earlier.  Just use `INSERT INTO dev (cin, comp) VALUES (?, ?)` and `$params = array_merge($cin, implode(',', $_POST['domaine']));`

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST["domaine"]` is an **array**, so puting it "as is" will result as "Array" in your database record.
You need to decide which type of "array->string" method is best for your app and use it before you insert into database.

Easiest way is to use a `join($sep, $_POST['domaine'])` or `serialize($_POST['domaine'])`.

Answer (score -2):

```
foreach ( $_POST["domaine"] as $aSelectedOption){
$rep=$cdb->prepare("insert into dev (cin,comp)values('$cin','".$aSelectedOption."') ");
$rep->execute();
}
```

this will insert an entry for each checked option

you could also use json_encode and json_decode though i wont suggest it.

Comment: You kind of just did suggest it.

Comment: this not gona work because it will create no of record for every item.